# Tracking cached redirects in database (database not initialized when redirected)

Tags: php, mysql, database, caching, redirect

I am looking for a way to serve cached redirects (via filesystem). So I would have a /cache/ folder with files like "google.txt" and using file_put_contents() insert 'http://www.google.com' into the 'google.txt' file.

The problem is that I want to actually track the ip's, views, etc.. in the database, but I want to redirect the user as quickly as possible. So I have created a simple flag function to be used. Here is some pseudocode to better illustrate:

```
if redirect_is_cached() //True if google.txt exists
   redirect_to_link() //actual redirect header(location:...)
   user_was_redirected_via_cache(TRUE) //STATIC: defaults to FALSE if no parameter is used.
   //No exit because I want to track data but database isn't loaded.

...

code snipped out...later on in the script.
...

db_connect(); //Now we can access the database

   if(user_was_redirected_via_cache()) { //TRUE since we flagged it earlier.
     track_redirect(); 
     exit();// Proper exit. We redirect user quickly, 
            // but continue script so we can track redirect.

   }
   else { continue with rest of script }
```

My questions are 1) does this follow "best practices" or is it kind of hackish? and 2) Does the user start getting redirected at the header() or the exit()? If the user doesn't start getting redirected until I actually exit() the script...this is kind of pointless.

Thanks for the help.